# How to show data from database when you click item in a listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

having a problem with trying to access data in my database when I click an item in my listview.

Here is my method in my database handler:

```
    public Match getMatchFromId(int matchId)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Match m = null;
        Cursor cursor;

        cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + MATCH_TABLE + " where " +
        MATCH_ID_COL + "='" + matchId + "'" , null);

        while(cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            m = new Match();
            m.setHome(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MATCH_HOME_TEAM_COL)));
            m.setAway(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MATCH_AWAY_TEAM_COL)));
            m.setHomeScore(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MATCH_HOMESCORE_COL)));
            m.setAwayScore(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MATCH_AWAYSCORE_COL)));
            m.setDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MATCH_DATE_COL)));
            m.setTime(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MATCH_TIME_COL)));
            m.setRedCard(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MATCH_REDCARD_COL)));
            m.setBookings(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MATCH_BOOKINGS_COL)));
            m.setTypeOfMatch(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MATCH_TYPEOFMATCH_COL)));
//            m.setGroundId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex()));
        }
        cursor.close();

        return m;
    }
```

I'm just having a problem with how to access the data via a listview. I want to be able to click the item, and bring it to another activity to edit it.

```
public class ViewMatchesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DBHandler myDB;
ArrayList<Match> matches = new ArrayList<Match>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_matches);
    myDB = new DBHandler(this);
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    matches = myDB.getAllMatches();
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(ViewMatchesActivity.this, R.layout.list2col, matches);

    listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Any help would be nice as I'm very new to Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a Listener to Listen to the respective event (likely Item Click). Then extract the id (or whatever can be used to uniquely identify the row in the table id or rowid (normally the same thing) is frequently used), place that data into an Intent Extra, after creating an Intent and then invoke the other activity using the Intent.

You could code something along the lines of :-

```
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //>>>> position is the position of the clicked item, 0 for the first item.
            //>>>> position will also be the respective offset into matches
            //>>>> position SHOULD NOT BE USED to try to perform arithmetic
            //>>>> calculation of rowid/id of the row in the table
            //>>>> So get rowid via matches.get(position).
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),your_other_activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("KEYFORDATA",row_id_to_so_selected_item_can_be_edited);
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Note! Obviously the above will not work as is, it will need to be tailored to suit.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I need to play around with it a bit more but that helps so much. I appreciate the help too, people on this site are too stuck up to give someone a hand who is only starting out.